# Configure nginx with style apache2 userdir

Tags: php, nginx

I need just configure my nginx server with style apache2 user_dir

I have my config file this sections:

```
   location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                 fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        }

  location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
             alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            autoindex on;
        }
```

This partially works, I see directories, index.html, but index.php does not work.

Which configuration should be correct? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To run PHP from a different root (i.e. `/home/$1/public_html$2`) you will need to use a nested location block.

For example:

```
location ~ ^/~(.+?)(/.*)?$ {
    alias /home/$1/public_html$2;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    autoindex on;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include        ...;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        fastcgi_pass   unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Notice that `$request_filename` is used as the path to the aliased file. The order of the locations will need to be reversed (as illustrated above), so that the correct location processed the URIs which end with `.php`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more.

You should add the appropriate `include` statement. The `snippets/fastcgi-php.conf` file may be suitable, otherwise use `include fastcgi_params;`.